# Why does python only return first line of text after removing stop words?

Tags: python

I am trying to remove stop words from my text document that contains multiple paragraphs, no tables. My code is below. When I print the data after removing the stop words it only returns the first line of the text file not all the paragraphs. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
data1 = pd.read_csv('001.txt', sep='\n')
```

```
stop = set(stopwords.words('english'))
```

```
def clean(doc):
    stop_free = " ".join([i for i in doc.lower().split() if i not in stop])
    return stop_free
```

```
data1_clean = [clean(doc).split() for doc in data1]
```

Comment: Why are you reading a text file as a .csv? We can't help you without a minimal, reproducible example.

Comment: when you loop over a dataframe like `for doc in data1` it just iterates theough the columns of the dataframe and not rows